# Error in Sending Emails Through Gmail in Symfony2

Tags: php, oracle11g, symfony-2.8

problem im getting

```
"Connection could not be established with host localhost [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. #10061]"
```

config_dev.yml:

```
swiftmailer:

transport: gmail
username:  '***'
password:  '****'
host:      'smtp.gmail.com'
auth_mode: 'login'
encryption: 'ssl'
```

config_test.yml

```
 swiftmailer:
  disable_delivery: false  //previously it was set it true
```

symfony2 code thats send email

```
 public function sendEmail($data = array())
{   

    try{            
        $mailer = $this->Container->get('mailer');
        $message = $mailer->createMessage()
                ->setSubject($data['subject'])
                ->setFrom($data['fromEmail'])
                ->setTo($data['toEmail'])
                ->setBody($data['body'], 'text/html');        
        if (array_key_exists('attachmentPath', $data) && $data['attachmentPath'] !== null) {
            $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($data['attachmentPath']));
        }
        return $mailer->send($message); //returns true or false upon success 
    }catch(\Exception $e){


        throw new \Exception('Exception occurred :- '.$e->getMessage(), 500);
    }        
}
```

url:http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html

another url :https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/issues/106

- disable macafeef,firewall anitivrus in localsystem.
- even then i cannot send email .
- please suggest is anything im missing

  parameters.yml

  ```
   parameters:
   database_driver: pdo_oci
   database_host: ***
   database_port: 1521
   database_name: **
   database_user: ***
  database_password: **
  mailer_transport: gmail
  mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
  mailer_user:  '***'
  mailer_password:  '***'
  ```
- is  database_port: 1521 is creating problem ?.

solution that worked for me

```
    swiftmailer:
      transport: smtp
      host: ***
     port: 25
    logging: true
    username: smtp
    password: ***
    delivery_address: ****
```

Comment: it sounds to me like you might have something in your parameters.yml file thats overriding the config files directly.  That error is telling you that its ignoring your 'hosts' key.

Comment: i have cross checked in parameters none of them override

Comment: Question: Are you using the DEV environment to test this? For example: you have `app_dev.php` in your URL?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `pdo_oci` as a database driver for Oracle, but instead `oci8`. You can read about it in [my blog on installing OCI8](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/category/oci8/). Oracle does not contribute to "PDO_OCI", so you shouldn't use that!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I ran into a similar problem: not being able to send emails from a gmail account.

In my case it was an VB application, so I don't really know if this will be related, but what ended solving it was setting the port to 587 (with tls it will probably be 465) and then allowing acces to "less secure apps" from the gmail account ([here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) is how to do so, should you need it).

Your config_dev.yml would then be like this:

```
swiftmailer:

transport: gmail
username:  '***'
password:  '****'
host:      'smtp.gmail.com'
auth_mode: 'login'
encryption: 'ssl'
port:      '587'
```

Comment: is database_port: 1521 is creating problem

Comment: not the database port but the email port, in config_dev.yml add the line: port: 587

Comment: i had a tough luck today this wouldn't works for me.